# gnome 3 hibernate option

Tags: gnome3

I switched to gnome 3 (which I like) and of all the things that have changed the only one that bothers me is the fact that there is not a hibernate option. Now, I know of the pm-hibernate command but it does not lock my x-window on boot up. Just right back into where I left off without requiring a password. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying a few different approaches, I got it to work with the instructions at the [webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/official-gnome-shell-extensions.html) site; installing all shell extensions.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-alternate-tab gnome-shell-extensions-alternative-status-menu gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme gnome-tweak-tool gnome-shell-extensions-workspace-indicator  gnome-shell-extensions-apps-menu gnome-shell-extensions-drive-menu gnome-shell-extensions-system-monitor gnome-shell-extensions-places-menu gnome-shell-extensions-dock gnome-shell-extensions-native-window-placement gnome-shell-extensions-gajim gnome-shell-extensions-xrandr-indicator gnome-shell-extensions-windows-navigator gnome-shell-extensions-auto-move-windows
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/gnome3
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-common
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-alternative-status-menu
```

And then restart or simply end the session. If all works you will see: [image: this].

Comment: didn't work... still have the same menu with "Suspend" being the only member of the bottom aspect of the menu (which switches to "Power Off..." when I press Alt key. I am running Ubuntu 11.10 x86_amd64 what else can I tell you?